# Why is my form not validating on submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit, form-submit

I have a sign up form on my page at http://business.uglyopportunities.com/affiliate-signup/ (scroll down to see the form)

Keep in mind, I am not very good with JS so this may be a simple error.

Anyways, here is the first line of my form telling it to validate:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="xxxxx" class="infusion-form" method="POST" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

and here is my validateForm javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myform"][" inf_field_StreetAddress1"].value;
    var e = document.forms["myform"][" inf_field_City"].value;
    var f = document.forms["myform"][" inf_field_State"].value;
    var g = document.forms["myform"][" inf_field_PostalCode"].value;
    var h = document.forms["myform"][" inf_other_Username"].value;
    var i = document.forms["myform"][" inf_other_Password"].value;
    var j = document.forms["myform"][" inf_other_RetypePassword"].value;

    if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name Here") {
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (c == null || c == '' || c == "Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9) {
        alert("Please insert your phone number!");
        return false;
    }
    if (d == null || d == '' || d == "Street Address”) {
        alert("Please insert your street address ");
        return false;
    }
    if (e == null || e == '' ||e == "City”) {
        alert("Please insert your city");
        return false;
    }

    if (f == null || f == '' || f == "State”) {
        alert("Please insert your state ");
        return false;
    }

    if (g == null || g == '' ||g == "Postal Code”) {
        alert("Please insert your postal code");
        return false;
    }
    if (h == null || h == '' || h == "Username”) {
        alert("Please insert your username ");
        return false;
    }
    if (i == null || i == '' ||i == "password”) {
        alert("Please insert your password");
        return false;
    }
    if (j == null || j == '' || j == "password”) {
        alert("Please re - type your password ! ");
        return false;
    }




    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and that is not working.  However, when I used this code, it worked fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() { 
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value; 
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value; 
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value; 
    if (a==null || a=="" || a=="First Name Here") {   
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (c==null || c==''|| c=="Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9) {
        alert("Please insert your phone number!");
        return false;
    }

    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1)  {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATED CODE *****

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_StreetAddress1"].value;
    var e = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_City"].value;
    var f = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_State"].value;
    var g = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_PostalCode"].value;
    var h = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_Username"].value;
    var i = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_Password"].value;
    var j = document.forms["myform"]["inf_other_RetypePassword"].value;

    if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name Here") {
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (c == null || c == '' || c == "Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9) {
        alert("Please insert your phone number!");
        return false;
    }
    if (d == null || d == '' || d == "Street Address") {
        alert("Please insert your street address ");
        return false;
    }
if (e == null || e == '' ||e == "City") {
        alert("Please insert your city");
        return false;
    }

    if (f == null || f == '' || f == "State") {
        alert("Please insert your state ");
        return false;
    }

if (g == null || g == '' ||g == "Postal Code") {
        alert("Please insert your postal code");
        return false;
    }
    if (h == null || h == '' || h == "Username") {
        alert("Please insert your username ");
        return false;
    }
if (i == null || i == '' ||i == "password") {
        alert("Please insert your password");
        return false;
    }
    if (j == null || j == '' || j == "password") {
        alert("Please re - type your password ! ");
        return false;
    }




    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What's in the JS console?

Comment: The ABC has more letters, use them all!!!

Comment: Instead of referring to your values as a, b, c etc - why not use name, email, phone...?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, as a thought you may want to look into using the jquery validate library to handle validations.  This type of 'alert' system is not very UX friendly and could really end up turning users off of your site.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses. What I mean by not working is that when I click the submit button, there is supposed to be something that pops up and says that you did not fill out a form if it was left blank, however there is no pop-up. And if I renamed my values, would this fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have a white space here:

```
var d = document.forms["myform"][" inf_field_StreetAddress1"].value;
//                                ^-----------------------
```

You have the same problem with for `e,f,g,h,i,j`

Also, you used the wrong quotes sign:

```
"Street Address”
//             ^--------------
```

You did it several times.

Comment: thanks for the help, but the white space didn't seem to matter as I changed it and it still isn't validating the function.  I am very new to javascript, so what do you mean by the JS console?

Comment: @user1953681, check the quotes signs.

Comment: I changed the quotes signs on it and now the form looks like this

Comment: Well, you can check the original question and I've posted the new code.  Still doesn't seem to be working. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

As gdoron says, it's probably an spelling problem. You cannot begin the name of an element with a whitespace http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Hi thanks.  I'm pretty sure I changed the whitespace issue, but the form is still not validating?